# Is there any way to know what version of windows is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So in my program i need to know if the program is running in, say, Windows 7 or 10. is there any method or module that can do that?

Comment: Use `platform` module. `platform.release()` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import platform


print("Platform :- "+platform.platform())
print("OS:- "+platform.system())
print("Version:- "+platform.version())
print("release:- "+platform.release())
```